# How to parse without changing the characters case (lower and upper) in wordpress the_content?

Tags: plugin-development, the-content

I made a custom parse function for my plugin and this one works great. I just have a little problem !

Here is my function :

```
public function ys_glossary_parse( $text )
    {
        // Get all the items in the database
        $terms = $this->get_all_termes();

        // Get the id of the glossary page
        $glossary_page_id = get_option('ys_glossary_PageID');
        if(!$glossary_page_id OR $glossary_page_id == 0)
        {
            return $this->admin_message('You don\'t have a Glossary page yet. Go in the option page !');
        }

        // Get the permalink of the page
        $permalink = get_permalink($glossary_page_id);

        $text_to_link    = apply_filters( 'ys_glossary_text', $terms );

        //$preg_flags      = $case_sensitive ? 's' : 'si'; // TODO: add an option for that
        $preg_flags      = 'si';

        $text = ' ' . $text . ' ';
        if ( ! empty( $text_to_link ) ) {
            foreach ( $text_to_link as $old_text ) {

                // TODO: modify this to use the upper/lower case of each words without modifying them

                $new_text = '<a href="' . esc_url( $permalink ) . '#'.$old_text.'" title="Lien vers la definition" target="_blank" >' . $old_text . '</a>';
                $new_text = apply_filters( 'ys_glossary_text_linked_text', $new_text, $old_text, $permalink );
                $text = preg_replace( "|(?!<.*?)\b$old_text\b(?![^<>]*?>)|$preg_flags", $new_text, $text );
            }
            // Remove links within links
            $text = preg_replace( "#(<a [^>]+>)(.*)<a [^>]+>([^<]*)</a>([^>]*)</a>#iU", "$1$2$3$4</a>" , $text );
        }
        return trim( $text );
    }
```

The $terms are in a simple array like :

```
array(
[0] => 'item1', 
[1] => 'item2', 
[2] => 'item3'
);
```

(they are with uppercase on the first letter).

What i want is :

How do i make the link on the words without changing the words case ?
**Blocking** will stay as **Blocking** but **blocking** will be **blocking**.
(So the uppercase and lowercase of the words stay as they are !)

I use the case insensitive but my function change all the words with a uppercase for the first letter because the terms are like that. But if i use lowercase on the terms, it change all to lowercase the_content.

So i need help on this.

Thank you very much ^^

Yann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kitefr, (this isn't really a WordPress question, but a php one) but you could use[`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), in which you define your own function to handle the the replacement.

For instance,

```
    $text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the Quick dog.";
    $text = preg_replace_callback( "/quick/si", 'my_replace' , $text );
    function my_replace($matches){
         return '<strong>'.$matches[0].'</strong>';
    }
```

This replaces all instances of 'quick' (in any case) and wraps them with strong tags, leaving the case of the letters unchanged. You could do something similar with link tags